# string.charAt() returning 0

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to print every letter of a word individually. The word is the variable string.

I've got the following code:

```
function typewriter() {
    var el = document.getElementById("typewr");
    var string = "Hello";

    for(var i=0;i<string.length;i++) {
        setTimeout(function(){el.innerHTML =+ string.charAt(i);},1000);
        }
}
```

(There's a `<div id="typewr"></div>` down in the `<body>` code and it's parsed by `<body onLoad="typewriter()">`)

But for some reason it's just returning 0 (after 1 second)

Why does it do that? How do I fix it? o.O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a closure to keep the value of `i`, then you need to increment the time for the timeout for each iteration as the loop doesn't wait for the next timeout etc, otherwise it wont work as all the timeouts will execute at the same time, and when they do `i` will be the last value it was set to :

```
function typewriter() {
    var el = document.getElementById("typewr");
    var string = "Hello";

    for(var i=0;i<string.length;i++) {
        (function(k) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                el.innerHTML += string.charAt(k);
            },k*1000);
        })(i);
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ReW39/1/)

I didn't change it, as it seems to be working, but as a general rule `string` is a really bad name for a variable, use `str` or something else that isn't already defined.

Answer (score 0):

el.innerHTML =+ string.charAt(i)

should not it be += instead of =+.

Comment: I actually wrote the the plus sign after the equals sign ("el.innerHTML =+ string.charAt(i);") o.O